# Missing Dropdown in Component Styles Tab in CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

In the TextImage component, the Style tab has lost the css selection dropdown that used to show up when editing the component. It now just shows a blank area. It should have a dropdown for image alignment (left or right are your choices). This doesn't appear anymore.

This tab is xtype *componentstyles* (String), so I don't know where it references the source for the dropdown values. My local instance of CQ5 works just fine.

I cannot just add an xtype selection and feed it values because the css that gets added to the JSP code is outside the component's .jsp-specific page

Comment: Though the css is outside the component, it should function appropriately. I don't understand why you cannot have an xtype selection. More details please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a design path variable went missing. We don't know why or how, but the solution is as follows.

- Open up Content Repository
- Go to /content/-sitefolder-/ and expand
- Click on jcr:content and view properties
- Check for attribute cq:designPath and its value
  /etc/designs/-sitefolder-; add to properties if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the ***componentstyles*** xtype is driven by the CQ design that is associated to the page.  Designs are stored underneath /etc/designs and are assigned through a page's Page properties dialog (cq:designPath property)

Let's look at an example in the Geometrixx website.  If you navigate to the English homepage @ **/content/geometrixx/en.html** and add an instance of the TextImage component to the page, you will notice that the Styles tab is empty in the component dialog.  Now navigate to the 'Discover Geometrixx' page @ **/geometrixx/en/company/discover_geometrixx.html** and examine one of the two pre-existing instances of the TextImage component.  The Styles tab has the image dropdown you mentioned!

So what is the difference between the instances on the 'Discover Page' and the 'Home' page?  The answer is in the design definition.  If you open up CRXDE Lite and navigate to the Geometrixx design page for the Content Page template (which the 'Discover Geometrixx' page adopts), you will see the following nodes:

```
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/par/textimage
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/par/textimage/cq:styles
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/par/textimage/cq:styles/imagealign
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/par/textimage/cq:styles/imagealign/image_left
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/contentpage/par/textimage/cq:styles/imagealign/image_right
```

The design for the Homepage template (which the 'Home' page adopts) is missing this definition.

If you want to continue to use the out of box TextImage component, it seems you will need to have this design configuration set up on all the paragraph systems and templates where the component can go.  So for example, if you want these styles to be available to the TextImage component when it is added to the **par** paragraph system of the Homepage template, you would add similar style nodes to:

```
/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/homepage/par/textimage/cq:styles
```

Alternatively you could just overlay the component and/or create your own.  Then for this custom component you could create your own Styles dialog that is independent of the design.  You can simulate the out of box behavior by examining the saved JCR property and setting the appropriate CSS class name in your render script.

Comment: I branched down to this location for our specific website (we have *standardpage* instead of *contentpage*, but it's the same thing under the hood), and the imagealign nodes do exist. This only makes it more puzzling on why the Styles tab remains empty.

Comment: @simonl could you please tell me, where is the code that appending / removing the css class names ?                                                             <div class="section textimage parbase cq-element-par_47textimage image_right" id="cq-gen526" style="opacity: 1;">